# Excel 2010 Macros

Tags: excel, vba, replace, find

I work with excel 2010 and have created a macro to copy a row of text data, transpose it into a column and then add commas after each value.  Now I want the same macro to also find a pre-determined value in the column and replace it with another pre-determined value.  Here is what I have so far...

```
Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro2 Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+q
'
    Range("E2:CL6").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("A11").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=True
    x = 1
    Do While Cells(11, x) <> ""
        Cells(11, x).Select
        Set Rng = Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown))
        For Each cell In Rng
         cell.Value = cell.Value + ","
        Next
        x = x + 1
    Loop
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Columns("B:B").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Cells.Select
    Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Range("B1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "user id"
    Range("C1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Pin"
    Range("B2").Select

End Sub
```

Comment: I want the values "Fixed Income Research Group" to be replaced with "SS FixedIncomeResearch"  and "Fixed Income Trading Group" to be replaced with "SS FixedIncomeTrading"

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code (a bit more cleaner without the `.Select`) :

```
Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro2 Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+q
'
    Range("E2:CL6").Copy
    Range("A11").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, _
                                Operation:=xlNone, _
                                SkipBlanks:=False, _
                                Transpose:=True

    x = 1
    Do While Cells(11, x) <> ""
        Set Rng = Range(Cells(11, x), Cells(11, x).End(xlDown))
        For Each cell In Rng
            cell.Value = CStr(cell.Value & ",")
            cell.Value = Replace(cell.Value, "Fixed Income Research Group", "SS FixedIncomeResearch")
            cell.Value = Replace(cell.Value, "Fixed Income Trading Group", "SS FixedIncomeTrading")
        Next
        x = x + 1
    Loop
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Columns("B:B").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, _
                            CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Columns("B:B").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, _
                            CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

    Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Range("B1").FormulaR1C1 = "user id"
    Range("C1").FormulaR1C1 = "Pin"

End Sub
```

Comment: This looks great and appears to work but now when I hit CTRL+Q nothing happens.  It only runs when I click on Macros, select the macro and select RUN.

Comment: OK so just reaffect the shortcut with another letter and then back again to Q, it might be enough! Is the rest ok? If it is please validate answer to mark your issue as solved.

Comment: The rest works great but even after assigning another letter and saving, then going back and reassigning the letter to Q and saving it still doesnt work when I hit CTRL+q.  In fact, nothing happens, no errors nothing

Comment: To be sure just add `MsgBox "this is running"`  into your code and try again. If nothing happen, then your shortcut is dead, try to close and reopen Excel and otherwise Google has probably an Answer for you!

Comment: Where do I add MsgBox "this is running"? - also I closed and reopened excel and it still doesnt work - corretion, i mean it works when i click the macros button and "run" the macro but not when I click "CTRL+q" anymore

Comment: Place it in any line of your code it doesn't really matter, at the start would be OK. For the shortcut, no clue why it disappeared ...